# How to un-approve github review after new commits automatically

Tags: github, github-codereviews

Once a pull request is approved, if there are further commits:

The Pull request should go to **un-approved** state automatically.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The ability to **Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed** is a setting under **Require pull request reviews before merging** in the [branch protection settings](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/). This is disabled by default.

[image: dismiss stale pull request]

Comment: Does this also invalidate approval if the branch is rebased?

Answer (score 9):

This isn't currently offered.

You can create an application that listens for `push` webhook events, queries the API for all Reviews for a Pull Request, and dismisses any that are **APPROVED**.

[Here is a Ruby script](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/hooks/ruby/dismiss-review-server/server.rb) you could host on heroku.