# GitHub Pull Request Review after approval

Tags: github, pull-request, review

We really like the approval feature on Pull Requests in GitHub, but we face some issue where I had approved something, then changes were made (new commits) but my approval remained, despite me having never seen the new changes.
We think it would be great if all approvals were reset when new commits are made to a pull request.

Thanks!

Comment: approvals are reset? you have to approve any new changes

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/41824374/1375964